# List contents of a tgz archive inside a gz archive

Tags: tar, compression, gzip, archive

Bit of a weird one - I've got a honeypot running `dionaea`, which is a tool that consolidates any binaries that were uploaded to the device in single location (`/data/dionaea/binaries`).

However, every so often (kind of like `logrotate`), the `/data/dionaea/binaries` directory gets gzipped into a file called `binaries.tgz.n` (where n is incremented each time the rotate happens), and then gets gzipped *again* into a file called `binaries.tgz.n.gz`.

I know with a normal `tgz` or `gz` archive you can list the contents of the archive with `tar tzf /path/to/tgz` and `gzip --list /path/to/gz` (or `tar zf /path/to/gz`) respectively, but is there a way to pipe the embedded archive into a new `tar` command to list its contents at the same time (instead of having to actually extract the "outside" `gz`)?

Comment: Are you sure it's gzipped? What does `file binaries.tgz.1.gz` give you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pipe to `tar`:

```
gunzip < /path/to/gz | tar tzf -
```

(Or with GNU tar, you can just use `| tar tz`.)

Comment: unfortunately that isn't working for me - see my edit in the OP

Comment: Uh, why are you using `gzip -k --list`?

Comment: *facedesk* you're absolutely right - in my stupor I just used the up-arrow to get a `gzip` command I had executed previously

Comment: The input *is* gzipped - `binaries.tgz.1.gz` contains `binaries.tgz.1` which is indeed a compressed archive.

Comment: Ah! So @ResetACK your system re-gzips already gzipped data? If so, the `z` is indeed needed. But that's a bit of a strange system... :)

Comment: Yes oddly enough it does double-zip